# macOS - No executable found matching command "dotnet-watch"

Tags: macos, .net-core

I am using the dotnet cli with macOS Sierra 10.12.6

I have typed this command:

`dotnet new web`

`dotnet run`

So far so good.

When I have change:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World");
            });
```

as per: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIkpVzqLuhA
and refresh the browser, nothing happens. I thought that this might need the watch package, so typed:

`dotnet add package Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools --version 2.0.0`

Which installs successfully; csproj contains:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

when I try to run `dotnet watch` or `dotnet watch run`, I get the error:

`No executable found matching command "dotnet-watch"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CLI tool needs to be referenced as `DotNetCliToolReference` instead of `PackageReference`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Currently, there is no CLI command to add a `DotNetCliToolReference`. In .NET Core 2.1, the `watch` command may be included with the CLI and the tools installation experience will be different (`dotnet watch` will be a global tool instead of a project-local tool).